# JPA - How to make field not required in JSON POST request

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I don't want to pass the price field in a JSON POST request, but to be computed by the setPrice() custom method.

When i pass the price field that i don't want to pass in a JSON POST request, no matter the value, it works and my field is correctly computed and stored in a MySQL table. When i don't pass it, it just returns and stores 0 for some reason.

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int user_id;

private String name;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", timezone = "Europe/Berlin")
private Date date1;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", timezone = "Europe/Berlin")
private Date date2;

private int beds;

private int meals;

private double price;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}


public void setPrice(double price) {

    this.price = (double) computePrice(date1, date2, beds, meals);
}

public int getBeds() {
    return beds;
}

public void setBeds(int beds) {
    this.beds = beds;
}

public Date getDate1() {
    return date1;
}

public void setDate1(Date date1) {
    this.date1 = date1;
}

public int getMeals() {
    return meals;
}

public void setMeals(int meals) {
    this.meals = meals;
}

public Date getDate2() {

    return date2;
}

public void setDate2(Date date2) {
    this.date2 = date2;
}


public long computePrice(Date date1, Date date2, int beds, int meals) {

    long duration = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);

    if (diffInDays < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    double priceBeds;
    double priceMeals = 700;

    if (beds == 1) {
        priceBeds = 2200;
    } else if (beds == 2) {
        priceBeds = 3300;
    } else if (beds == 3) {
        priceBeds = 4100;
    } else {
        priceBeds = 0;
    }

    if (meals < 0 || meals > 3) {
        meals = 0;
    }

    return (long) (diffInDays * (priceBeds + (meals * priceMeals)));

}
```

Comment: Your use case is precisely past the fine line beyond which the approach of entities doubling as DTOs breaks

Answer (score 0):

You are using `double` primitive for the price field. The default value for double primitive is 0, so when not passed, it is initialized to it.

If you'll use `Double` object, the default value when not passed will be null

Comment: Now it just returns null. Is there a way to not pass a price field value at all? I want it to be computed by setPrice() method, and not passed by the user.

Comment: It depends how you serialize your response to json, but ye, you should use a sieriallizer that ignores null values